# My 320px width adsense unit is too small on newer smart phones

Tags: css, responsive-design, mobile-website, adsense

I have a 320px x 50px adsense unit I am trying to display on an iPhone 6.  (Or any mobile browser with a width more than 320px - iPhone 3Gs was 320px wide.)  The ad unit is way too small.

I tried using CSS, media queries, and other things.  No dice.

I tried using Google's Responsive ads.  No dice.

I looked at a bunch of sites with the **Google Chrome device mode** and found a site that had a 320px wide add, but it was taking the full viewport width on an iPhone 6!

How can I get the ad to display on the full width of the page?

Comment: Did you add meta viewport tag inside the head section? It is a must have for mobile-optimized websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With all of the different device screen sizes, now there is a way to set the viewport size on mobile browsers.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

This will scale the 320px width ad unit to fit the full width of the device.

[More reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).

Answer (score -1):

try this add it you your CSS

```
img
{
max-width:100%;
}
```

I think will work with you.